# Exporting special chacacters from PDF

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I have a PDF with a character that looks roughly like a backwards `g` [image: Example]and is typed using the WP font (it is a "k" in that symbolic font). When I export the text this gets logically switched to a `k`. I believe using alternate fonts for special characters was common before the expanded Unicode character set was established?

I want to be able to get this text out in some way which allows me to either:

1. Have the correct character be represented in the text or
2. Have the characters be replaced with a placeholder I can then do a replacement with.

I have tried exporting in several ways using various PDF export tools including acrobat pro, as well as look for a way to search and replace in the document for a k in that font, but I am at a loss. Does anyone have a loose thread I can pull at on this?

In preflight I can see all the pages with at-issue characters (there are several others besides the example above), but this is thousands of needed replacements in the first document alone.

Comment: So you want the file to replace all of the backward g-ish things with Ks? Automatically? Is this correct?

Comment: No - the backwards g is a k in the wingdings like WP symbolic font. I nned to convert it to a unicode version of that letter in the PDF or replaces all k's of font type WP with something I can substitute back in later (like AAA).

Comment: If you're on OSX or Linux maybe take a look also at [U&L](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)?